# How do I instantiate a Java 7 completion handler in Scala

Tags: scala, nio2

I was playing with scala (newbie) and I was trying to use Java 7 NIO (because I like to start easy). But I can't work out how to instantiate the [CompletionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html) for the accept. The following code is wrong and I can't fix it:

```
package async

import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel

class AsyncServer (port: Int) {

  val socketServer = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open();
  socketServer.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port))

  val connectionHandler = new CompletionHandler[AsynchronousSocketChannel, Integer](){

  }

  def init() = socketServer accept(1 ,  connectionHandler)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to create the `connectHandler` instance, you need to implement the `CompletionHandler` methods:

```
...
val connectionHandler = new CompletionHandler[AsynchronousSocketChannel, Integer] {
  def completed(result: AsynchronousSocketChannel, attachment: Integer ) {}
  def failed(exc: Throwable , attachment: Integer) {}
}
...
```

And, because the interface type is invariant in A, but the method you're calling is contravariant in A:

```
...
public abstract <A> void accept(A attachment,
                                CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel,? super A> handler);
...
```

you need to cast to make the types check:

```
socketServer accept(1, connectionHandler.asInstanceOf[CompletionHandler[java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel, _ >: Any]]
```